# Like onomatopoeia, but visual

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Onomatopoeia is [defined](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/onomatopoeia) as:

> The formation of a word from a sound associated with what is named (e.g. cuckoo, sizzle).

Is there a term for describing the formation of a word from a **shape/image** associated with what is named; and/or a word so formed?

The oldest word like that I can think of would be

[delta](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/delta#delta-2)

> A triangular tract of sediment deposited at the mouth of a river, typically where it diverges into several outlets:
>
> Origin: Mid 16th century: originally specifically as the Delta (of the River Nile), **from the shape of the Greek letter**

The newest I can think of would be [XOXO](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=xoxo) (O and X are crude visual representations of a hug and a kiss respectively). I know it's arguably not a word, still...

Then we have words like [U-turn](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/U-turn), [T-bone](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/T-bone) and [V-neck](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/V-neck), which are named after the shape of the letter (as against words like X-rays, A-team and B-boying)

Is there any term that describes words like this?

PS - If there isn't, neologisms are welcome in comments.

Comment: Don't forget I-beam and U-channel.

Comment: Are you looking for a term for these? http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/words-used-to-describe-the-shape-of-objects

Comment: @Josh61: I'm afraid not. Those are words that describe shapes. I'm looking for a term for words named after shapes.

Comment: @Catija: Also, U-, J- and S-bends.

Comment: Coming up with a neologism is going to be tricky, because the original Greek literally translates to "[the making of a name or word](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=onomatopoeia)." The closest I can get is "morphonoma," which is roughly "shape-word." (Or "onomatomorph," if morphonoma sounds too much like a disease for you.

Comment: I guess "boxing ring" fails.

Comment: But isn't the Pentagon named the Pentagon because it is a pentagon, not just takes the form of a pentagon? Same for baseball diamond. IOW, we call a circle a circle because it is a circle, don't we?

Comment: @SomethingDark: I know. When I saw the etymology didn't have a ref to sound, I got puzzled. "onomatomorph" sounds good, though. People have a shot of guessing. Morphonoma sounds too much like a disease, indeed. Like weird-shape cancer.

Comment: @pazzo: You could make the same argument for some onomatopoeic words like meow. Point is, they're not called Kickass Security Base or baseball ground.

Comment: Onomatopoeia is an *imitative* act, whereas giving the name *crescent* to a crescent-shaped area is simply to call a spade a spade.  Maybe the word should be limited to naming things after the shapes of letters in the alphabet?

Comment: @TimRomano: Yeah, I guess you guys are right. Edited.

Comment: maybe the question should be: are there any long verbal visual languages where non-letter shapes intuitively represent or activate mental states associated with meaning.

Comment: There are multiple ways to answer this, depending on what you are really looking for. At first it sounds like you are looking for a word for words (or writing) whose shape is patterned after the actual object. But all your examples though seem to be the reverse, shapes in the world that are named after letters. The first is like some basic Chinese characters, the second like U-turn. Which are you really looking for?

Comment: Another example: the sex act, to "69".

Answer (score 7):

They are simply called ***shape words***.

It is mentioned in Jeff Miller's *[Collection of Word Oddities and Trivia](http://jeff560.tripod.com/words4.html)*; and coined by Dan Tilque:

> Dan Tilque has compiled a list of what he calls "shape words," terms in English that are composed of a single letter and a word (or two), where the letter describes the shape of the object.
>
> He attempts to show one word for each letter of the alphabet, but several letters are missing. His list: A-frame, C-clamp, D ring, f-hole, F clamp, G clamp, H hinge, I beam, J-bar lift, K truss, K-turn, L square, M roof, O-ring, P trap, S curve, T-shirt, T-intersection, T-bone, T-square, U-turn, V neck, W-engine, X truss, Y theodolite, and Z bar. [Mark Brader and Phil Jacknis added to Dan's list.]

[Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=593) mentions the same source and adds that formal documents  used such terms freely. It is also mentioned that other languages have similar words. For example, in Chinese, there are shapes that correspond to Chinese characters.

> 十字路口, a "十 intersection", refers to a four-way intersection (or just any intersection). The phrase is based entirely on the shape of the character, and not the meaning (十 means ten in Chinese).

<sub>Further details for Chinese characters:
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/words-referring-to-the-shape-of-chinese-characters</sub>

It is also described as ***using letter shapes as analogies*** in *[A Biography of English Language](http://npu.edu.ua/!e-book/book/djvu/A/iif_kgpm_Biography_of_the_English_Language.pdf)* by C.M.Willmard:

[image]

Comment: XOXO might be an exception but there is no reason not to call it a shape word.

Comment: What about delta?

Comment: @TusharRaj: Hmm I missed that one but I think "delta" is not exactly in the same category as others. But again, you can still call it a "shape word" :) It is not represented with an English letter but as a whole word. (and the word is the name of a letter in Greek alphabet).

Comment: I think I'll have to. But the _'what he calls shape words'_ part troubles me. It's like the author's saying: "Don't look at me. His term, not mine." Anyway, upvoted.

Comment: @TusharRaj: Thanks. Well, someone coined it; but we can extend the meaning. A neologism may also be a new usage of an existing word (semantic extension).

Comment: Yeah, but I wish he had coined something more sophisticated. My cousin in second grade could have come up with `shape word`!

Answer (score 5):

The word **phenomime** can be used for words that act like onomatopoeia (also known as *phonomimes*) for non-auditory sensory stimuli (the other four senses). They are quite common in Japanese, which also has *psychomimes* (words that act like onomatopoeia for emotions, thought processes, states of mind).

- *Phonomimes* use word sounds to represent auditory stimuli, such as a bark, a meow, or a honk.
- *Phenomimes* use word sounds to represent non-auditory stimuli, such as a flash, a twinkle, or a grope.
- *Psychomimes* use word sounds to represent psychological stimuli, such as the pitter-pat of a quickened heart, dizziness, or reluctance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are referring to metaphorical names.  Many anatomical terms are formed this way.  For instance, the piriformis muscle is so named because it is "pear-shaped," and the trapezius muscle is shaped like a trapezoid. Many more everyday terms are formed the same way, such as "crescent roll,"  which resembles the shape of the crescent moon.  There is a list on Wikipedia here:

[Glossary of shapes with metaphorical names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_shapes_with_metaphorical_names)

Comment: Hi user. Thanks for answering. Unfortuanately, you seem to have misunderstood the question. I'm not looking for names of shapes. 'Metaphorical names', if that's what your answer is, is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can come for

> a word from a shape/image associated with what is named

is

[Hieroglyphyc](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hieroglyphic?showCookiePolicy=true)  from

> Hieroglyph:  a **picture or symbol** representing an object, concept,
> or sound

or, even simpler, you could say that the written form of the word is **figurative**

> representing by means of an emblem, likeness, figure, etc
>
> (painting, sculpture) of, relating to, or characterized by the
> naturalistic representation of the external world

For example,  a U-turn is in the shape of what it is represented.

Comment: Thanks P. But Hieroglyphs are representations of objects or sounds, very much like letters/symbols/icons. I'm looking for an umbrella term for objects named after shapes. Not quite the same thing.

Comment: I like this, even if some might feel it is off topic. This answer simply describes visual representations of visual objects, the same way as onomatopoetica is audible representation of sounds. The question really asks us to compare apples with oranges.

Answer (score 0):

Ever seen a picture of Union General Ambrose Burnside?
We could use the eponym "Burnside" for such words.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, Dewey. What the comment above implies is that, for words and phrases, D-I-Y suggestions are off-topic as ELU looks at verifiable usage.

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to suggest **morphograph**.

***morpho-*** from the Greek for *“shape”*

***-graph*** from the Greek for *”writing”*

Morphography would be the process of writing words in the shape of what they represent.

e.g. **CaMeL**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, NP. What the comment above implies is that, for words and phrases, D-I-Y suggestions are off-topic as ELU looks at verifiable usage.